# Substring garbage in C

Tags: c, substring

I want to make a program that cuts a string into 2 strings if the string contains a `?`

For example,

```
Test1?Test2
```

should become

```
Test1 Test2
```

I am trying to do it dynamically but at the prints I get some garbage and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(expression);i++){

        if(expression[i]=='?' || expression[i]=='*'){
            position=i; break;

        }
    }

    printf("position=%d\n",position);

    if(position!=0){
        before = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(position +1 ));
       strncpy(before,expression,position);
       before[strlen(before)]='\0';

    }

    if(position!=strlen(expression))
    {
        after = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*( strlen(expression)- position+1));
        strncpy(after,expression+position+1,strlen(expression)-position+1);
        after[strlen(after)]='\0';

    }

    printf("before:%s,after:%s\n",before,after);
```

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. `char first[] = "first?second"; char *p = strchr(first, '?'); *p = 0; char *second = p + 1;` <- after this, `first` will contain the first part of the string, and `second` will point to the beginning of the second part. If you want to just *replace* the question mark with a space, then do `*p = ' ';` instead. Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)!

Comment: You might want to look into e.g. [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).

Answer (score 3):

Since it is illegal to take length of a string until it is null terminated, you cannot do this:

```
before[strlen(before)]='\0';
```

You need to do this instead:

```
before[pos]='\0';
```

Same goes for the `after` part - this is illegal:

```
after[strlen(after)]='\0';
```

You need to compute the length of `after` upfront, and then terminate the string using the pre-computed length.

Comment: Ok! Thx for advide I will tag the answer as soon as possible!

Comment: Another problem is that position is not initialized if no separator character is found - so probably he'll get a segfault at the second strncpy().

Comment: @ldx I am not sure about that, because there is no declaration of `position` shown in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
  for(i=0;i<strlen(expression);i++){
```

This is very inefficient. `strlen(expression)` gets computed at every loop (so you get an O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity, unless the compiler is clever enough to prove that `expression` stays a constant string and then to move the computation of `strlen(expression)` before the loop.....). Should be

```
  for (i=0; expression[i]; i++) {
```

(since `expression[i]` is zero only when you reached the terminating null byte; for readability reasons you could have coded that condition `expression[i] != '\0'` if you wanted to)

And as [dasblinkenlight answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20938486/841108) you should not compute the `strlen` on an uninitialized buffer.

You should compute once and for all the `strlen(expression)` i.e. start with:

```
size_t exprlen = strlen(expression);
```

and use `exprlen` everywhere else instead of `strlen(expression)`.

At last, use [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html):

```
 after = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*( strlen(expression)- position+1));
 strncpy(after,expression+position+1,strlen(expression)-position+1);
 after[strlen(after)]='\0';
```

should be

```
 after = strdup(expression-position+1);
```

and you forgot a very important thing: **always test against failure of memory allocation** (and of other system functions); so

```
    before = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(position +1));
```

should really be (since `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1):

```
    before = malloc(position+1);
    if (!before) { perror("malloc of before"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Also, if the string pointed by `expression` is not used elsewhere you could simply clear the `char` at the found `position` (so it becomes a string terminator) like

```
    if (position>=0) expression[position] = `\0`;
```

and set `before=expression; after=expression+position+1;`

At last, learn more about [strtok(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), [strchr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html), [strstr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html), [strpbrk(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strpbrk.3.html), [strsep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html), [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)

---

BTW, you should always enable all warnings and debugging info in the compiler (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger**  (like `gdb`) to step by step and understand what is happening... If a memory leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is available, use it.

Comment: Are you sure for expression[i] ? You confused me a lot.

Comment: @Mario - `expression[i]` will return true when there is value. on null terminated string, it will return false as soon as you hit the null terminator.

Comment: @alvits Thx.. Withought your explanation I woyldn't understand it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sry I didn't mean to offend you

Comment: I am not at all offended!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsep`

```
char* token;

while ((token = strsep(&string, "?")) != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n", token);
  }
```

Comment: (delimiters are `?` and `*` for the OP)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it manually, you can also make good use of `strtok()`. Check the details [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).